# How to check how application was started

Tags: android

My app can start because of different reasons. Either user started it or device location changed (PendingIntent), geofencing event (PendingIntent), etc.

I need to know when app is started in background (because of intent) so I can check for a condition, and if condition is true, display a notification.
If the app is started in foreground (user clicked on it), I need to show a dialog when activity starts.

Comment: The intent that started your application will tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

Put your identifying data like some int value in intent you are using in pending intent as Extras.
You will get this intent in `onReceive` Method of `BroadCast` receiver.
Try to define Pending intent as below.

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Does this mean I need to put the extra data in ALL intents I am using ? :\
I was hoping to avoid this...

Comment: Its  not like that. You are passing just an id as Integer. I'll find some better solution, if i find any will update here.

Comment: Yes, but I need to do this all over the app and keep remembering it to do it in all places

Comment: what does `getCallingActivity` return when user launched the app from main screen?

Comment: else putExtra, what are you expecting to do like?